# React-Native, how to animate textAlign of a multi-line Text?

Tags: react-native, animation, text

I am using react-native 0.60, I need to animated a multiline  props textAlign from "center" to "left".

I tried to do it using Animated.Text and LayoutAnimation but they only animate frames. 
So I had the idea to split my multi-line Text into multiple one line Text that I could animate separately but I failed and it looks like a dirty workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `textAlign: 'center'`, but animate the prop `minWidth`:

```
const minWidth = animatedValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: ['100%', '0%'],
});


<Animated.Text
  style={{
    textAlign: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    minWidth,
  }}
>
  Example text
</Animated.Text>
```

So if the `minWidth` will be 0%, then the text will be aligned to the left.